asset validation failed invalid executable. the executable 'myapp.app/frameworks/cardio.framework/cardio' contains bitcode
I encountered this problem after updating to macOS 15 Sequoia and the latest version of Xcode 16. I'm getting this error when trying to publish the build from Xcode.
Does anyone know the solution?

Ensure that bitcode is turned off for all of your frameworks and tatgets

@Paulw11 yes i checked everywhere even i have added config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
in pod file also

Is the cardio framework something you have created or something you have imported/added?  That framework needs to be rebuilt without bitcode

It happens on Sonoma macOS too

I was getting the same issue after upgraded to Xcode 16 and iOS 18.
You can solve this issue by  following this.

Open Podfile

Search for word post_install

If post_install not found then just directly paste the below code just before the last end keyword
 post_install do |installer|

 bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end


In case you have already post_install has been used then copy and past the below script inside that.
   bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end


Do pod install

Run build now :)



This solution worked for me as well.

If you have empty space in a folder inside your path this will return error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/bitcode_strip: more than one input file specified (Path/After/Space/ios-arm64_armv7/Something.framework/Something and /First/part/Of/the/Path)
Usage: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/bitcode_strip input [-r | -m | -l] [-keep_cs] -o output

Add or remove the framework_paths as per your project. This soltion helped me.

How do we achieve this in the React Native Expo EAS project? How do we identify the framework path as Pods, which are runtime created in eas only?

how to solve for any dependecy that doesn't use framework such as glog and double-conversion? When upload the .ipa to app store there is an error. However, in the Podfile there is no framework file

@NicholasBiantoro could you have resolved? Both are in my react-native (expo) project and I have no idea where they come from...

What is bitcode?
Bitcode is an intermediate representation of an app’s compiled code that allows Apple to optimize app performance and compatibility.
With Xcode 16, Apple has deprecated bitcode for all platforms, meaning that builds with bitcode enabled are no longer accepted.
Execute this command in Pods folder of your project:
xcrun bitcode_strip -r YOUR_PATH/USED_FRAMEWORK -o YOUR_PATH/USED_FRAMEWORK

Notes:

Replace YOUR_PATH with your own used framework directory path.
Replace USED_FRAMEWORK with your own used framework name.

Example:
xcrun bitcode_strip -r Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit -o Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit

Repeat this command for your all used frameworks which are reported as "contains bitcode" in the errors/logs panel when you’re uploading app to AppStore.

Should I rebuild the app, re-archive after stripping bitcode with your command?

Yes, You should rebuild and archive again.


In the Pod folder, locate your framework.
Open the .xcframework.
Find the ios-arm64 folder.
Open .framework.
Locate the Unix Executable File named after the framework and note its path.


For any framework, try to locate it and add it.
Example down with Shake bugs framework.
Add this line within the above answer:
"Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
  "Pods/Shake/Sources/Shake.xcframework/ios-arm64/Shake.framework/Shake", # <------ this line.
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"


I encountered the same issue and resolved it using the following steps:
post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(installer)

  # Path to bitcode_strip
  bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chomp

  def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
    command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
    puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
    system(command)
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
    end

    if target.name == 'YourFramework'
      device_framework_path = 'Pods/YourFramework/YourFramework/YourFramework.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7_armv7s/YourFramework.framework/YourFramework'
      simulator_framework_path = 'Pods/YourFramework/YourFramework/YourFramework.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/YourFramework.framework/YourFramework'
      
      # Strip bitcode from both binaries
      strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, device_framework_path)
      strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, simulator_framework_path)
    end
  end
end

Explanation:

Bitcode Stripping: This script uses the bitcode_strip tool to remove bitcode from specified frameworks.
Paths: Make sure to replace 'YourFramework' with the actual name of your framework.

Reference:
For more context, you can check this Bitrise discussion.
Thanks!

This will work, if you're creating build for ios 18 and new xcode version
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'MapboxMobileEvents'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxMobileEvents/MapboxMobileEvents.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents -o Pods/MapboxMobileEvents/MapboxMobileEvents.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents`
      end

      if target.name == 'MapboxCommon'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxCommon/MapboxCommon.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCommon.framework/MapboxCommon -o Pods/MapboxCommon/MapboxCommon.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCommon.framework/MapboxCommon`
      end

      if target.name == 'MapboxCoreMaps'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxCoreMaps/MapboxCoreMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps -o Pods/MapboxCoreMaps/MapboxCoreMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps`
      end
    end
  end


Where to add this code in podfile ?

i have a quick fix for this issue, once you build your ipa, run this command to strip bitcode from the issue causing framework(in my case it was VdoFramework) :
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip  ios/Pods/VdoFramework/VdoFramework.xcframework/ios-arm64/VdoFramework.framework/VdoFramework -r -o ios/Pods/VdoFramework/VdoFramework.xcframework/ios-arm64/VdoFramework.framework/VdoFramework 

run this command for all issue causing framework.
Now run testflight upload command:
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file $IPA_PATH --apiKey $API_KEY --apiIssuer $API_ISSUER --verbose


How do you find your path, here is simple trick:

first step when your archive build is successful then the modal will show where you validate the app.
here if the erros comes like
Invalid Executable. The executable '***.app/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/hermes' contains bitcode. (ID: 37fb02b5-0173-4c01-8d79-88a9cf6a33d8)
then you have to do, how you can handle this just do copy this from your error and placed in the below solution

framework_paths = [
      "Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKShareKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKShareKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit",
      "Pods/FBAEMKit/XCFrameworks/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics",
      "Pods/FBSDKGamingServicesKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKGamingServicesKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKGamingServicesKit.framework/FBSDKGamingServicesKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit",
    ]

All the lines in framework_paths are errors that come when I try to validate or upload the build. So most people face issue here that they don't know how to find the path of this framework, So you don't need to find it using commands.You can just use this template and if in your case different frameworks causing this bitCode error then just simply replace them. In my case if I receive the error of hermes-engine then what I will do I simply copy this from xcode and replace it
  "Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit",

  "Pods/hermes-engine/XCFrameworks/hermes-engine.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes-engine.framework/hermes-engine",


here I replace FBSDKCoreKit ---> hermes-engine
FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework  ---> hermes-engine.xcframework
FBSDKCoreKit.framework  ---> hermes-engine.framework
FBSDKCoreKit  ---> hermes-engine

In this way you can solve this error. So finally what you have to write in pod file
replace this code portion
react_native_post_install(
   installer,
   # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
   # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
   :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
 )
 __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

with--------------------->
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
    def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
      framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
      command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
      puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
      system(command)
    end

    framework_paths = [
      "Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKShareKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKShareKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit",
      "Pods/FBAEMKit/XCFrameworks/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics",
      "Pods/FBSDKGamingServicesKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKGamingServicesKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKGamingServicesKit.framework/FBSDKGamingServicesKit",
      "Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit",
    ]

    framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
      strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    end
    

Thats it

All the solutions here are good but if you have issue where it says
glog.framework or double-conversion.framework or something similar for which you cannot find direct files in Pods folder use the approach below.

Use the find command to find the exact pods that are using the above (lets assume you get glog.framework issue) then use


find Pods -name glog

This will list all the folders where glog is being used.
In my case it was these folders

Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/glog.framework/glog
Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/glog.framework/glog
Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/glog.framework/Versions/A/glog
Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/glog.framework/glog

Now just use these folders in the above given approach
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!

def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
  framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
  command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
  puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
  system(command)
end

framework_paths = [
  "Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks/OpenSSL.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL",
  "Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.xcframework/ios-arm64/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay",
  "Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/glog.framework/glog"
  "Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/glog.framework/glog"
  "Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/glog.framework/Versions/A/glog"
  "Pods/Flipper-Glog/Frameworks/glog.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/glog.framework/glog"
]

framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
  strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
end


Now do pod install in the ios folder
Everything should work smoothly after this

